# Build Griffon app for Windows and Linux

Tags: build, griffon

I am going to build desktop application for Windows and Linux both. I tried to use Swing with Java, but it's a bit too rough. Right now I have focused on the Griffon framework.

Is it possible (I bet it is) to build application for Windows (exe file) and Linux (other executable file) ? How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can build an app targeting several platforms. In terms of deployment, i.e, creating platform specific installers/launchers have a look at the Installer plugin

http://artifacts.griffon-framework.org/plugin/installer

Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Is that url still available? I guess the plugin should appear in http://griffon-framework.org/plugins.html also, but I can't find it. Thank you Andres.

Comment: No, sadly that URL is no longer available as the Griffon 1.x plugin portal was shutdown Dec 31st 2015. There's no longer a need to use a custom Griffon installer plugin as Griffon can use Gradle (or Maven) as build tool. One must use the build tool's options to create a native installer. there are plenty of options in Gradle and Maven to do so.